# Sequelize Not Creating a Through Table

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to associate a User model and an Age model with a many to many relationship. The user and age model are being created however the through table isn't. Here is my code:

```
const { Sequelize, Op, QueryTypes } = require('sequelize')
const db = new Sequelize('postgres://localhost:5432/sqlstuff', {
  logging: false
})

const Age = db.define('Age', { age: Sequelize.INTEGER }, { timestamps: false })

const User = db.define('User', {
  firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
  lastName: Sequelize.STRING,
}, { timestamps: false })

async function create() {
  try {
    //Both Users and Ages Table are created. Both tables are properly populated
    const people = await User.bulkCreate([
      { firstName: 'Tyler', lastName: 'Kumar'},
      { firstName: 'Sabi', lastName: 'Kumar'}
    ], { validate: true }, { fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']})
    const myAge = await Age.create({ age: 22 })
    //Line 21 and 22 do not create a through table, unsure why
    User.belongsToMany(Age, { through: 'UserAges' })
    Age.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'UserAges' })
    //Line 23 creates the error 'relation "UserAges" does not exist'
    await people[1].addAge(myAge)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

async function connect() {
  try {
    await db.sync({ force: true })
    await create()
    await db.close()
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

connect()
```

Comment: You might just want to try doing the belongsToMany() calls *before* the User.bulkCreate() and Age.create() calls.

Comment: @Kevin Perry That didn't work, however I figured out the problem. The belongsToMany associations can't happen inside the function as it isn't scoped properly. I believe the associations have to be scoped to the connect call or the db.define, not quite sure. I am sure however scope was the problem.